Change calling convention in compiler-explorer gcc x86-64
Out of curiosity, I wanted to understand the different calling conventions like cdecl or fastcall. So I look at the documentation from gcc and it seems we can use the cdecl or fastcall attributes in order to set the calling convention of a function. So I tried it out in this compiler explorer but the fastcall attribute is ignored. How could I fix this?

In 64-bit code fastcall and cdecl are the same - they are both fastcall. If you build 32-bit code using -m32 GCC option then they are different.

@MichaelPetch, thank you for the comment. Indeed using -m32 did produced a different code for fastcall and cdecl. Also, checking wikipedia again with your comment in mind, I see they say that there is only two calling conventions left in 64-bit code : Microsoft calling convention and System V calling convention. And indeed using __attribute__((ms_abi)) or __attribute__((sysv_abi)) changes the produced code.

The only question I still have in mind is : why a 64-bit code make the different calling conventions obsolete?

I think CDECL was first created without registers in 16 and 32-bit code because of the limited number of registers available. With the advent of the x86-64 the number of registers increased so the thinking was that there were enough t dedicate to parameter passing.
